# Apple script with Bash SU Authentication ( Automator)

Tags: bash, automator

I have a bash scrips pasted into "Run shell script " Action in Automator apple script under 10.9.3 and the command is copy command a dll to system folder  /Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/VST/ that is read only.

I need to prompt the user that runs the script to enter the password. what is the way to to that?

Thanks!

Comment: run your script as `sudo`.

Comment: script runs inside automator (Apple script) not from terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If it's short enough, you can instead use Run AppleScript, and use:

```
do shell script "command" with administrator privileges
```

That will prompt the user for administrator username and password in the GUI and then run "command" as root.

**Update per comment below:**

I missed the part about copying into a privileged folder. You can't use Automator's "Run Shell Script", because it doesn't support running commands as administrator (it's not interactive, so sudo doesn't work). So there are a couple of different ways you could solve the problem.

To run your Bash script as an administrator, save your Bash script as a typical script you run in Terminal. After the Automator action to choose the file, use the "Run AppleScript" action. Then put in the code below. You'll see no prompt and no Terminal window; it will just execute.   (If you do want a prompt, you can get one in the GUI by omitting`user name "username" password "password"`.) The folder the user chose will be the argument to the Bash script.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    do shell script ("sudo /path/to/yourscript '" & POSIX path of input & "') ¬
        with administrator privileges user name "username" password "password"

end run
```

An alternative approach: A Terminal window will open with the prompt "Password:", and the user will enter their password (presumably, it's an administrator). Then your script will run as administrator and be able to copy into the privileged folder.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "Terminal"
        do script "sudo /path/to/yourscript '" & POSIX path of input & "'"
    end tell

end run
```

Or, if you really want to put your Bash script in Automator under "Run Shell Script" as you have currently, and the copy instruction is at the end, you could take the copy instruction out, and have it instead echo the folder the user chose as its final instruction. This will return it to the next Automator action. After Run Shell Script, put in a Run AppleScript with a `do shell script` command as shown in the first example above, that contains a `cp` command in place of /path/to/yourscript, with administrator privileges.

Comment: my main scrips is bash script and i use automator just to prompt the user to locate a folder location , once the user select that im back to the BASH script. my script takes files and placed then in system folder. the folder i mentioned is read only. how do i copy into it without prompting the user ( or prompt in the script beginning for authorization ).

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I've expanded my answer; hope it helps.